# Constructing Identity Matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have tried to solve an algorithm problem, I'm newbie and I'm trying to practice a lot in programming problems. So I wanted to construct an Identity matrix n*n. I came up with a stupid solution, that worked for a 4*4 matrix, but it didn't work with 5*5. I know that its weird solution and the solution to the problem is really easy when I looked at it. I need to know what did I do wrong so that I can learn, and is my solution is really stupid and I will be better in the future after working much in solving those kind of problems ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>  // for setw, setfill

using namespace std;

int binary(int number);

int main()
{

    vector<vector<int> > matrix;

    cout<<"Please enter the size of the identity matrix"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    matrix.resize(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {

        matrix[i].resize(n);
    }

    int steps = 1<<n-1;

    int bin  = binary(steps);
    ostringstream binString;

    binString <<bin;
    if(binString.str().size()<n)
    {
        std::string dest = binString.str();
        int nPaddings = n-binString.str().size();
        if (nPaddings==0) nPaddings=1;
        dest = std::string( nPaddings, '0').append( binString.str());
        binString.str("");
        binString<<dest;
    }
    for (int col = 0; col<n; col++)
    {
        if(col>=1)
        {
            steps= (int)steps/2;
            int bin = binary(steps);
            binString.str("");
            binString << bin;
            if(binString.str().size()<n)
            {
                std::string dest = binString.str();
                int nPaddings = n-steps;
                if (nPaddings==0) nPaddings=1;
                dest = std::string( nPaddings, '0').append( binString.str());
                binString.str("");
                binString<<dest;
            }
        }
        for (int row=0; row<n; row++)
        {
            matrix[col][row] =binString.str().at(row)-'0';
        }
    }


    return 0;
}

int binary(int number) {
    long rem,i=1,sum=0;
    do
    {
        rem=number%2;
        sum=sum + (i*rem);
        number=number/2;
        i=i*10;
    }while(number>0);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is really your problem ?

Comment: The code has still some flaws. There is byte offset by one error.

Comment: I would suggest having a separate identity matrix empty class and overload all relevant operations between it and other matrices as non-ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do it.

First, you should allocate your matrix with the specified size. Then, you know that only the diagonal is `1`s:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
int n;

cout << "Please enter the size of the identity matrix" << endl;
cin >> n;

// Initialize the matrix as a n x n array of 0.
matrix = vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>(n,0));

// Set the diagonal to be 1s
for(unsigned int t = 0; t < n; t++)
    matrix[t][t] = 1;
```

You can see a live example [here](http://ideone.com/T82CmE).

### Edit:

Your error comes from this line:

```
int nPaddings = n-steps;
```

In fact, you're not using the size of `dest` to compute the padding, which is not correct. [See here](http://ideone.com/X0A8k0), I added some debug printfs to see the state of the variables. You can see that `nPaddings == -3`, hence the errors.

The idea you have:

```
for each column
    get the representation of the column as a string
    set the i-th value of the column as the i-th character of the string
```

So, here is a simpler program using your idea. Separating the code in several functions helps a lot. Also, `std::ostringstream` and `std::string` is just pure overkill here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>  // for setw, setfill

using namespace std;
std::string binStr(unsigned int exponent, unsigned int size);

int main()
{

    vector<vector<int> > matrix;

    cout<<"Please enter the size of the identity matrix"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;

// Initialize the matrix
    matrix.resize(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
        matrix[i].resize(n);

// Fill the matrix
    for (int col = 0; col<n; col++)
    {
        std::string bin = binStr(n-col,n);
        for (int row=0; row<n; row++)
            matrix[col][row] = bin[row]-'0';
    }


// Print the matrix and return
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < n; y++)
    {
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < n; x++)
            cout << "\t" << matrix[y][x];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

std::string binStr(unsigned int exponent, unsigned int size)
{
    // You do not need a string stream (which is like using a bazooka to kill a fly...)
    // Instead, just create a string of the required length
    // 'str' will contain the binary representation of 2^exponent
    std::string str(size,'0');
    if(exponent <= size && exponent > 0)
        str[size - exponent] = '1';
    return str;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/bNe1xN).

Comment: Thanks, but what's your comment about my solution, is it good, bad ? I'm trying to practice more in problem solving.

Comment: I am currently trying to understand why you wanted to use stringstream for this code. Maybe a little explanation of what you think you've done in english will be useful (at least for me).

Comment: I have tried to get the binary code for each row, then I tried to pad leading zeros into the string to complete one row :), then I constructed the identity matrix out of those binary codes, like 1000,01000..etc

Comment: Ok. I am writing some improvements to my answer. This can take some time.

Comment: I would like to comment about my idea :/

Comment: Here you are, I found your error. Also, I improved your idea, even if I think using strings here is a bad idea.

Comment: is it bad :) ? how do you rate it out of 10 for a first trial of programming tasks..

Comment: Why it's bad ? It is not efficient, and is also a lot more error-prone (as you've made the experience^^). I'm not a teacher, but I think the correct mark would have been something like 5 or 6 / 10 (before searching for complex solutions, search for simple ones first!).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > make_idty_matrix( int n )
{
    vector<vector<int> > idty( n, vector<int>( n, 0 ));
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        idty[i][i] = 1;
    return idty;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > matrix = make_idty_matrix( 5 );

    // your code here
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```